# Am I using flatMapConcat correctly?

Tags: android, kotlin, repository-pattern, kotlin-flow

I'm migrating from RxJava to Flow.  In RxJava, I used Observable's concat method to emit a list stored in room first, then a list from a network request after.  In Flow it looks like the equivalent is flatMapConcat.

```
@Singleton
class StoreRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val remoteDataSource: StoreRemoteDataSource,
    @DatabaseModule.DatabaseSource private val dbSource: LocalDataSource,
    @NetworkModule.IoDispatcher private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ) {



    @OptIn(FlowPreview::class)
    suspend fun getStoreFeed(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): Flow<List<Store>> = flow {
        withContext(dispatcher) {
            dbSource.fetchStores().flatMapConcat { localStores ->
                remoteDataSource.getStoreFeed(latitude, longitude)
                    .onStart {
                        Log.d("TRACE", "emit local stores while remote")
                        emit(localStores)
                    }
                    .onEach { remoteStores ->
                        Log.d("TRACE", "insert into room db")
                        dbSource.insertStores(remoteStores)
                    }
                    .catch { e ->
                        if (localStores.isEmpty()) {
                            Log.d("TRACE", "nothing in db and network fails")
                            // If both local and remote data sources fail, propagate error
                            throw e
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my repository function my injected dispatcher is Dispatchers.IO provided by dagger 2.

in my viewmodel I try to observe 2 emissions from getStoreFeed using the collect method

```
class StoreFeedViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val storeRepository: StoreRepository
): ViewModel() {

    private val _storesResult = MutableLiveData<ResultState<List<Store>>>()
    val storesResult: LiveData<ResultState<List<Store>>> = _storesResult

    fun initializeFeed() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _storesResult.postValue(ResultState.Loading)
            try {
                storeRepository.getStoreFeed(
                    Constants.DEFAULT_LATITUDE,
                    Constants.DEFAULT_LONGITUDE
                ).collect { storeList ->
                    Log.d("TRACE", "received ${storeList.first()}")
                    _storesResult.postValue(
                        ResultState.Success(storeList)
                    )
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.d("TRACE", "exception fetching from reppsiotry ${ex.message}")
                _storesResult.postValue(
                    ResultState.Failure("failed to get stores")
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

added print statements but none print out and debugging does not stop at any of those linies.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you wrapped your concatenated flow inside a `flow` builder that never emits anything, so it returns an empty flow that, when collected, creates a cold flow that is promptly released to the GC.

The code inside looks to me like it would work, but it's fragile. Stepping through the logic:

- `flatMapConcat` is called on the source cached data, so every time you modify the database, everything inside will repeat. Not what you should want. After the cached data is emitted, you wouldn't want to have cached data redundantly overriding additional values that come in from the network. And you wouldn't want to keep immediately restarting your fetch from the network.
- Within the inner flow, you are caching the newly fetched values. This will trigger the top source flow to emit another item. This is essentially an infinite recursive loop.
- If `dbSource.fetchStores()` is an infinite Flow, then the loop problem shouldn't occur because the very first of the concatenated flows will never complete. This is why I said I think it actually would work.
- If `dbSource.fetchStores()` is a finite flow, I think you have a conceptual problem. If you're fetching something one time, it should be a suspend function returning `List<Store>` directly, or it could be (less common) a non-suspend function returning a `Deferred<List<Store>>`. A Flow is for a series of items. For  getting something from a network, I can't think of a reason you want to do it a specific number of times other than 1 or infinity.

Aside from that, this function should not be marked `suspend` because all it's doing is creating a cold Flow.

Since we shouldn't want to restart every time the database is updated, `flatMapConcat` isn't even an appropriate solution. I would do it as follows, assuming `dbSource.fetchStores()` is an infinite Flow:

```
fun getStoreFeed(latitude: Double, longitude: Double): Flow<List<Store>> = flow {
    Log.d("TRACE", "emit local stores while remote")
    // we emit only the initial value of database flow, the current cached value:
    val localStores = dbSource.fetchStores().first()
    emit(localStores) 

    // Then we can emit the rest from the network, while also caching them.
    val remoteFlow = remoteDataSource.getStoreFeed(latitude, longitude)
        .onEach { remoteStores ->
            Log.d("TRACE", "insert into room db")
            dbSource.insertStores(remoteStores)
        }
        .catch { e ->
            if (localStores.isEmpty()) {
                Log.d("TRACE", "nothing in db and network fails")
                // If both local and remote data sources fail, propagate error
                throw e
            }
        }
    emitAll(remoteFlow)
}.flowOn(dispatcher)
```

I used `flowOn` because it reduces indentation of code as compared to `withContext`. I think it's questionable that you should even need to specify a dispatcher since none of the code in this flow appears to be blocking or work with UI.

Comment: wow thanks for your in deoth response.  A couple of questions 1) why use emitAll and not emit 2) what dependencies did you use, I'm getting "exception fetching from reppsiotry Unable to invoke no-args constructor for kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<? extends java.util.List".  Using retrofit 2.9.0 currently and it looks like I need to add converterfactories to my retrofit instance ie             .addConverterFactory(Json.asConverterFactory("application/json".toMediaType()))
.addConverterFactory(FlowConverterFactory.create()) but those lines aren't compiling for me.

Comment: For the local cache, we pull the current value from the database by getting the first value of the flow and emitting just that. But for the the flow of values we want to follow up with, we want the whole flow so we `emitAll()`. I'm not using any libraries. I just typed out a modified version of your code and didn't test it because I don't know what your functions are. I still think it's super weird that `getStoreFeed` returns a Flow in the first place, but giving you the benefit of the doubt that you meant to have it return an infinite flow that repeatedly fetches maybe with some time interval

Comment: Maybe your problem is that you defined `getStoreFeed()` as a retrofit function that returns a Flow, which doesn't make sense. It should be a suspend function that returns a single thing. A find it a bit weird that Retrofit lets you return Observerables instead of just Singles, but maybe they wanted to be extra flexible. And when they added coroutine support, maybe they rethought how weird that is so it doesn't support Flows the way it supported Observables.